# Delete dynamically added fields

Tags: jquery

I am adding fields dynamically in jquery. But I also intend to eliminate these fields dynamically.
I'm trying to delete it like this example:

```js
var cars = [
   {colour: "red", },
   {colour: "white", },
   {colour: "black", },
];

var campos_max = 10; 

var x = 0;
$('#add_field').click (function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 

 if (x < campos_max) {
    $('#listas').append(`<div class="teste"><select class="form-control1 Reff reff${x}" name="Ref[]"></select></div><button class="remove_field" style="background-color: #313348;"><span class="fa fa-trash fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>`);
 
}

var html = $(`.reff${x}`);

cars.forEach(element => {
  html.append(`<option value="`+element.colour+`">`+element.colour+`</option>`);
    });
    
    x++;
});

$('#listas').on("click",".remover_campo",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.teste').remove();
    x--;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listas"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-warning caixa"><span class="material-icons">add</span></button>
```

But it doesn't delete the field I added.

Comment: Where is element with class `remover_campo`?

Comment: @Karan It's inside the append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly the button class is `remove_field`, not `remover_campo`. Secondly, `.teste` is a sibling of the button not a parent so you should use `prev()` to target it.

In addition there's a couple of things you can do to improve the code, such as building the list of colour options just the once, avoiding the use of a global variable (`x`) to track how many `select` elements have been appended, and removing the 'Remove' button itself when it's clicked. Try this:

```js
let cars = [
 { colour: "red", },
 { colour: "white", },
 { colour: "black", },
];
let campos_max = 10;
let carOptions = cars.map(o => `<option value=${o.colour}">${o.colour}</option>`).join('');

$('#add_field').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('.teste').length >= campos_max)
    return;
    
  $('#listas').append(`<div class="teste"><select class="form-control1 Reff" name="Ref[]">${carOptions}</select></div><button class="remove_field" style="background-color: #313348;"><span class="fa fa-trash fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span>Remove</button>`);
});

$('#listas').on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev('.teste').addBack().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listas"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-warning caixa"><span class="material-icons">add</span></button>
```